# Universal Audio Apollo Solo not working with MacOS Sonoma

Tags: mac, audio

I have recently purchased a [Universal Audio Apollo Solo](https://www.uaudio.com/audio-interfaces/apollo-solo.html) audio interface and want to use it with a Mac Pro 2019, running MacOS Sonoma.

According to [this article](https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/19237390771860), the device should be compatible, but I don't see either the device registration page when restarting the machine, and I don't see the device anywhere in system or audio settings.

I have connected the device to my Mac with a [Thunderbolt 4 USB C-C cable](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0BRNYNCNK?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details&th=1)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you reinstall? Do you have SIP disabled? [That will prevent it asking for authorisation].

Comment: @Tetsujin no I haven’t tried disabling SIP, although I didn’t see anything in the instructions indicating that I should. I’ll give that a go.

Comment: No, SIP needs to be on - so many people seem to disable it so they can do things they're not supposed to, but it prevents apps asking permission. Just do a standard reinstall & follow UA's instructions.

Comment: @Tetsujin it has asked for permission to install, so I guess that would indicate that SIP is enabled.

Comment: @Tetsujin weirdly, it seemed to be an issue with the thunderbolt cable not being oriented correctly...I though these bi-orientation cables were supposed to be...well...bi-orientable :/

Comment: hmmm… you'd think so ;))